# Eigenvalues of the circle over the Laplacian operator

Tags: spectral-theory, laplacian

I would like to find the spectrum of a circle. It seems that there are no boundary conditions, but I'm not quite certain. How could I find the spectrum of a circle over the Laplacian operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a solution, but a sketch. You need to find a manageable expression for $\Delta f$ if $f:S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. One option is to work with a (almost onto) chart of $S^1$, e.g. by using an arclength parametrized curve $c:(-\pi,\pi)\rightarrow S^1$ and by looking at the resulting equation for $f\circ c$ instead. The fact that $f$ is assumed to be continuous on the circle imposes a periodicity condition on $g:=f\circ c$. I'm rather sure (but did not check, you should do that) you'll end up with the equation
$ g^{\prime\prime} = \lambda g$ for the eigenvalue equation in this setup, which implies together with the periodicity condition that the corresponing solutions are given by $\sin(kx)$ and $\cos(kx)$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, so the spectrum will consist of the squared integers (multiplicities to be calculated, be careful with the sign). (Assuming I did not make a silly mistake on my way to the result).

*Edit*: maybe I should add that I, without proof, assumed that the spectrum consists of Eigenvalues only.

Comment: I've succeeded to do this problem by using the definition of the Laplacian in local coordinates : impa.br/opencms/pt/biblioteca/cbm/29CBM/29CBM_05.pdf (the 1st formula ). However, you method seem very interesting, but I don't know how to use it. Could you explain to me in details what you did so far to obtain the spectrum of the circle?

Comment: @Dr.Dray What I did is to propose to transform the problem into a setup where you can write it down explicitly. An arclength parametrization of a curve is nothing but a (local) isometry, so from a local ODE point of view I just get a representation of the same problem. Now for the spectrum I need to solve the equation taking into account side conditions (there are no boundary conditions) and the topology. The latter point is addressed by looking at periodic functions. A peridoc function on $(-\pi,\pi)$ extends to a unique continuous function on the circle under the given transformation.

Comment: Could you explain to me how you got an explicit formula in function of $sin(kx)$ and $cos(kx)$ from the equation $g''=\lambda g$?

Comment: @CharlesMcKay By calculation, one solution of $g^{\prime\prime}=-\mu^2 g$ is $a\cos (\mu x) + b\sin(\mu x)$ (this I consider well known, so I did not start deriving it). Since we are talking about a second order ODE the space of solutions is 2 dimensional, so in principle  we have all solution given by that formula. Since we need to have a period of $2\pi$, the choice for the value of $\mu$ is, by inspection,limited to the integers. (The minus sign you see here is my reason to write that you have to be careful with the sign). The admissible values for $\lambda$ are therefore of the form $-k^2$

Comment: Are you certain that $\lambda$ is on the form $-k^2$, but $\lambda$ is defined to be strictly greater than $0$ by definition of an eigenvalue?

Comment: @CharlesMcKay that depends on the sign convention you are using, i.e wheter $\Delta = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ or $\Delta =- \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$. Both conventions are in use. I do not know which convention the OP (or you) has/have in mind, but I _am_  sure that the second derivative of $\cos( kx) $ is $= -k^2 \cos(kx)$, so it's quite obvious that these are eigenfunctions and there is no doubt about the value of the scalar multiple. See, e.g, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator, section spectral theory.

Comment: I think you use the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Are you able to display a full solution of your problem?

Comment: @CharlesMcKay what do you mean by 'full solution of my problem'. It's not 'my'  problem by the way.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but could you at least explain rigorously why the periodicity of $c$ implies that solving $f''= \lambda f$ is equivalent of solving the DE $g'' = \lambda g$?

Comment: @CharlesMcKay $c$ is a local diffeomorphism which covers $S^1$ with the exception of a single point $p$, i.e. $c^{-1}$ is a chart of $S^1 \backslash \{p\}$ This means any $C^0$ funtion $f$ on $S^1$ has the property that $f\circ c$ is periodic. Conversely, any periodic function $g$ on $(-\pi, \pi)$ induces a $C^0$ function $f= g\circ c^{-1}$, since it admits a continuous extension. Similar reasoning applies to smooth functions. So $c$ induces an isomorphism of the various corresponding function spaces (actually an isometry)  on $(-\pi,\pi)$ and $S^1$. I'm just solving the transformed equation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And Could you explain why spectrum will consist of the squared integers?

Comment: @CharlesMcKay I already did. The _eigenvalues_ will be squared integers. This is because the solutions are of the form $a\cos (b x)$ or $a\sin (bx)$, which is possible only if $b$ is an integer, since that function has to be periodic with period $2\pi$. (If you are not looking at the unit circle, this will of course change). This implies $\lambda = b^2$ (or $-b^2$, depending on how you define the Laplace operator) is a squared integer.