# Spectrum of the circle - Clarification of certain points

Tags: circles, spectral-theory

I have a bit of difficulty as doing the problem [Eigenvalues of the circle over the Laplacian operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790675/eigenvalues-of-the-circle-over-the-laplacian-operator). Since $g$ is a periodic function, do I have to use the Fourier series? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: I think all you have to do is showing that with the radian-angle chart for $S^1$, it reduces to $g'' = \lambda g$ with $g$ being $2 \pi $ periodic $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: for a given (smooth) chart $\varphi : S^1 \to (a,b)$, let $g(x) = \varphi(f(\varphi^{-1}(x)))$, hence $f(p) = \varphi^{-1}(g(\varphi(p)))$. can you write how to express $\Delta f$ from $g$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 According to my supervisor : "In fact you can easily find the spectrum of the circle (it is a closed manifold so no boundary condition is needed)." How could it possible to find the spectrum of the Laplacian on the circle knowing that the circle is a closed manifold?

Comment: did you learn this definition of the Laplacian in local coordinates : http://www.impa.br/opencms/pt/biblioteca/cbm/29CBM/29CBM_05.pdf (the 1st formula ) ? what do you get if $g$ is constant (the angle parametrization of $S^1$, the length parametrization of any curve) ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure the first option you want to say; i.e. what page?

Comment: the first formula of the pdf, the definition of the $\Delta$ operator in manifolds in term of local coordinates $x_i$ and the metric $g$. and I'd say that if the manifold is a $1$-manifold homeomorphic to the circle, we can choose the  coordinates such that $g$ is constant and $=1$, and it reduces again to the eigenvalue equation $h'' = \lambda h$ with $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ and $L$ periodic

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: (I'm still curious to know what definition you learnt for $\Delta$ in manifolds)

Comment: I thought to understand your point of how finding the spectrum of the circle, but it is again unclear. Could you explain in details how to obtain it by using ΔΔ operator in manifold.