# Periodic function with the capacity of being $g'' = \lambda g$

Tags: continuity, spectral-theory, periodic-functions

Related to the question : [Eigenvalues of the circle over the Laplacian operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790675/eigenvalues-of-the-circle-over-the-laplacian-operator), what kind of periodic chart $c:(-\pi,\pi)\rightarrow S^1$ has the property that for a continuous function $f$, $g :=f \circ c$ is periodic, and such that $g'' = \lambda g$ as in the Thomas's comment?

Comment: and to be clear : what you want is a derivation/explanation for defining the differential operators, in particular the Laplacian, in manifolds, and how it can be independent of the choice of coordinates (which is what we expect from a linear operator in a manifold)

Comment: so $c$ is not a chart, it is a smooth function $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$, which can be chosen to be periodic, for example $c(x) = (e^{ix})$ where $(e^{ix})$ is the point of the circle in $\mathbb{C}$.  this way $c$ is $2\pi $ periodic, and the Laplacian becomes easy to define since this is also the length parametrization of the circle, i.e. the metric $g$ in the local coordinates defined by the chart $(c\mid_{[x_0,x_0+2\pi)})^{-1}$ is constant and $=1$

Comment: I have a lot of difficulty of understanding how to use this information in using the Laplacian in local coordinate. I am not familiar with this operator, and I would like that someone to show me. Could you take time to show me how it works in using what you did so far?

Comment: I don't know what is your level. It seems that even the metric is not a concept that you like so much. So : how do you define a $1$-dimensional (Riemannian) manifold ? Do you have 2 relevant examples ?

Comment: I know well what is a d-dimensional manifold $T$consists of the following structures:  (1) topological space T
(2) An atlas of charts $\phi_\alpha: U_\alpha \to V_\alpha$, which are homeomorphisms from open sets $U_\alpha$ in $T$ to open sets $V_\alpha \in {\Bbb R}^d$, such that the $U_\alpha$ cover T. So a curve (ex : simple line or circle) in general is a 1-dimensional manifold.

Comment: then consider a function $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ with $M$ being a 1-dimensional manifold. and suppose that for some (smooth) chart $\phi : T \to \mathbb{R}$ having a (smooth) inverse on some open $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and that when $h \to 0$ : $\displaystyle\quad f(\phi^{-1}(x_0+h)) = f(\phi^{-1}(x_0)) + h \alpha + \mathcal{O}(h^2)$. what can you say of $\alpha$ ? in particular what can you say of $ f(\varphi^{-1}(x_0+h))$ where $\varphi$ is another (smooth) chart $\varphi : M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(x_0) = \phi^{-1}(x_0)$ ?

Comment: So to answer your question, we know that $f(g(x))= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{f^{(n)}(\alpha) (g(x)-\alpha)^n}{n!}$. Hence, $f \circ \phi^{-1} (x+h) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(f \circ \phi^{-1})^{(n)}(x_0) (x+h-x_0)^n}{n!} = f \circ \phi^{-1} (x)+(f \circ \phi^{-1})'(x)(x+h-x_0)+\mathcal{O}((x+h-x_0)^2) \implies \displaystyle\quad f(\phi^{-1}(x_0+h)) = f(\phi^{-1}(x_0)) + f'(\phi^{-1}(x_0))h + \mathcal{O}(h^2) $; it is clear that $\alpha = f'(\phi^{-1}(x_0))$. Furthermore, by using the previous result, as $\varphi^{-1}(x_0) = \phi^{-1}(x_0)$, then $f(\varphi^{-1}(x_0+h)) = f(\phi^{-1}(x_0+h))$.

Comment: you are assuming that $f$ is analytic ? and no by the Taylor expansion and the chain rule $f(\varphi^{-1}(x_0+h)) = f(\varphi^{-1}(x_0)) +\beta h + \mathcal{O}(h^2) = f(\phi^{-1}(x_0)) +\beta h + \mathcal{O}(h^2)$ with $\beta = \alpha \ \ [(\phi \circ \varphi^{-1})'](x_0)$.

Comment: As $f''=\lambda f$, we are assuming that $f$ is at least $C^2$. So normally my first answer has to be good, right?

Comment: no.. but if $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is  $C^2$ around $x_0$ then $f \circ \phi^{-1}(x_0+h)) = f \circ \phi^{-1}(x_0) + h\ (f \circ \phi^{-1})'(x_0) + \mathcal{O}(h^2)$ (what I wrote)

Comment: but the biggest problem is that you wrote $g(x)-\alpha$ as if we could substract/add points of the manifold... so my advice : read a fucking course on manifolds (after having read what I wrote)

Comment: I think I can finish this problem by myself. Thanks a lot for you help, I appreciate!