# Periodic function - Differential equation on an existing question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory, periodic-functions

Related to the question : [Eigenvalues of the circle over the Laplacian operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790675/eigenvalues-of-the-circle-over-the-laplacian-operator/1790707#1790707), how could I get an explicit formula for the differential equation $g''=\lambda g$ with $g$ a $2 \pi$-periodic function. As $g$ is periodic, I think I could define it as a Fourier series $g(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n \geq 1} a_1 \cos(nx)+b_1 \sin (nx)$.

I know that normally a differential equation $y'' - \lambda y=0$, with $\lambda \geq 0$, as a explicit function of the form $y(x)=c_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x} + c_2 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$. However, this can't be the case since $g$ is periodic.

Is anyone could help me to find $g$ explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed approach is fine: plug in $g$ into both sides of your equation and you will get
$$g'' = \sum_{n\geq 1} -a_n n^2 \cos(nx) - b_n n^2 \sin(nx)$$
$$\lambda g = \frac{\lambda a_0}{2} + \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n \lambda \cos(nx) + b_n \lambda \sin(nx).$$

There is something special and fortuitous about the basis you have chosen for $g$: compute
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)^2\,dx &\quad \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)\cos(mx)\,dx\\
\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(nx)^2\,dx &\quad \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(nx)\sin(mx)\,dx\\
\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)\sin(nx)\,dx &\quad \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(nx)\sin(mx)\,dx
\end{align*}
for $n\neq m$. What do you notice?

Now compute
$$\int_0^{2\pi} g''\cos(kx)\,dx \quad \textrm{and} \quad \int_0^{2\pi} \lambda g\cos(kx)\,dx$$
for an integer $k$. What can you conclude about the possible values for $a_k$? Now do the same for $b_k$ using sines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is a better way of doing this question (curiosity)?

Comment: @CharlesMcKay You should be able to solve the problem at a glance once you realize that 1) this is the Helmholtz equation on the round circle, and 2) the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the round circle has well-known spectrum. There is no trick to solving the problem on more general manifolds, beyond computing the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $\Delta$.

Comment: I was wondering as I am not familiar with with Helmholtz equation and Laplace-Beltrami operator, would you be able to solve the problem with it?