# The particularity of $k$ being an integer in the solution of a DE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, laplacian

Related to the Thomas's comment in the question : [Eigenvalues of the circle over the Laplacian operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790675/eigenvalues-of-the-circle-over-the-laplacian-operator), is there anyone could tell me why the periodic function $g$ has a fundamental set of solutions of the form $c_1 \cos (\mu x) + c_2 sin (\mu x)$, where $\mu \in \mathbb{Z}$? Someone told me that is related to the Laplace equation and the boundary condition $u(0)=u(2 \pi)$ $u'(0)=u'(2 \pi)$ but it is very unclear for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, the problem is $u''+\lambda u=0$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with periodic boundary conditions. (Note that this interval has the same length as the circumference of the circle; this choice of parametrization ensures that the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the circle directly corresponds to the Laplacian on this interval.) The solutions to the DE itself are sinusoids with angular frequency $\lambda$. The boundary conditions can be satisfied if and only if $\lambda$ is a nonnegative integer (so that $2 \pi$ is a period).

Edit: you need $\sin(\lambda(-\pi))=\sin(\lambda(\pi))$ and $\cos(\lambda(-\pi))=\cos(\lambda(\pi))$. If you let $-\lambda \pi=x$ then you need $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2\pi\lambda)$ and $\cos(x)=\cos(x+2\lambda \pi)$, which is true if and only if $\lambda$ is an integer. Now $\lambda$ also had to be nonnegative in order to get the sinusoid solutions in the first place, so the admissible $\lambda$ are the nonnegative integers. (This means the eigenvalues in the usual sense are the non*positive* integers.)

Comment: Could you only prove the part : "The boundary conditions can be satisfied if and only if $λ$ is a nonnegative integer (so that $2π$ is a period)"?

Comment: @Pineuf Done. ${}{}$

Comment: I would like to learn to properly use the  Laplace-Beltrami operator, but I can not very well. I think the parameterization arc length allows to assert your note. We also know that the circle is a closed $1$-dimensional manifold. Can you explain to me how that note can be useful to me in this problem?

Comment: @Pineuf Ultimately you will go in circles until you have defined the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the circle; until then you have not really specified the problem. *As it happens*, the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the circle has the property I described, which allows you to do what I said. Why that is the correct Laplace-Beltrami operator depends on some manifold theory that I don't really want to deal with here.

Comment: I think it is much more easier to proceed with LB operator. If I ask a question related to LB and $S^1$, would you be motivated to show me how it works?

Comment: @Pineuf Not really, I don't have the appropriate background to give a rigorous explanation in terms of manifold machinery. It winds up going basically this way anyway, the only real issue is determining what the right LB operator is).

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but once I have managed to show that $\mu \in \mathbb{Z}$, how to I find $c_1$ and $c_2$? I am not quite sure how I have to do.

Comment: @Pineuf They can be anything if all you need is an eigenfunction. You would calculate these coefficients if, say, you had to expand some given function in the eigenfunction basis.

Comment: In this eigenfunction, I would like  to extract its spectrum, that's why I need to explicitly compute coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$. I guess you mean that I have to expand $\cos (\mu x)$ and $\sin (\mu x)$, but I don't know the relevance of that. Could you explain a little bit further what you mean.

Comment: @Pineuf If $\mu$ is a nonnegative integer then the eigenspace corresponding to $\mu$ is the span of $\{ \cos(\mu x),\sin(\mu x) \}$. So there is no "finding" of $c_1,c_2$ to be done. You can identify a *basis* of eigenfunctions by choosing particular sets of values of $c_1,c_2$ of course...

Comment: In your words, what rigorously would you do to find the spectrum of the circle with the proper function that we currently have?

Comment: The spectrum of the circle is the set of $k$'s for which there is a solution. @Pineuf, you seem to be confused about that,